# Fail to putstate in hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When i want to write some data to the fabric ledger, the chaincode call command seems well, and no error, but i found nothing written into the couchdb.

```
func (t * NumberGenerator) GenerateNumber(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface,args []string) peer.Response{
num,err := strconv.Atoi(args[0])
if err!= nil{
    return shim.Error("internal error")
}
size,err  := stub.GetState("size")
sizeNum,_ := strconv.Atoi(string(size))

rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
for i:=0;i < num;i++{
    id := strconv.Itoa(sizeNum+i)
    num := rand.Intn(100)-50
    numStr := strconv.Itoa(num)
    err := stub.PutState(id, []byte(numStr))
    fmt.Println(id,num)
    if err != nil{
        return shim.Error("fail to save the data")
    }
}
sizeNum += num
err3 := stub.PutState("size",[]byte(strconv.Itoa(sizeNum)))
if err3 != nil{
    return shim.Error("fail to update the size")
}
return shim.Success([]byte("success to generate number"))
```

i can see the logs in docker,

```
fabric@ubuntu:~/Desktop/fcc/fcc/fabric-samples/fcc$ sudo docker logs -f dev-peer0.org1.example.com-dataGenerator-1.00 -18 1 31 2 -3 3 -25
```

but i found nothing in the couchdb, and PutState function returns no error , who can tell me why?

this is the command i use to call the chanincode function

```
    #!/bin/sh

CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=golang
CC_SRC_PATH=github.com/chaincode/dataGenerator

CONFIG_ROOT=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
ORG2_MSPCONFIGPATH=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
ORG3_MSPCONFIGPATH=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp
ORG3_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt
ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode invoke \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
    -C mychannel \
    -n dataGenerator \
    -c '{"Args":["GenerateNumber","2"]}' \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
```

Comment: and the orderer logs : 2021-10-29 14:29:11.207 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 09a streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=192.168.16.13:32940 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=12.487171ms

Answer (score 0):

The data is not written to the ledger when PutState() is called. The chaincode execution produces a peer endorsement to write some data to the ledger in a transaction. The client then gathers the endorsed results from the peers and submits the executed transaction and endorsements to the ordering service, and once a block is cut each of the peers then validate the block transactions and write any validated transactions to the ledger.

Check your peer logs to verify that they have committed the block with the transaction and that there are no invalidation warnings. For example a transaction can get invalidated if different peers produced different endorsed results. I mention this because your chaincode has a `time.Now()` call, which is guaranteed to be slightly different across each peer execution and cause invalidation if your endorsement policy is more than one peer (which it should be).

Answer (score 0):

The contract is forbidden to contain uncertain values such as random numbers and time.

Delete your code about `rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())`